# Pagetab Dialog failing

Tags: facebook, request, facebook-apps

I am currently trying to attach a custom tab to a page. I do this by calling https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id={my_app_id}&redirect_uri={my_tab_landing}

This results in a error:

**Sorry, something went wrong.**

We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Its in this state for 2 days now, anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized - is related to temporary bug

Answer (score 1):

Appearantly there is new url in town;

https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key={YOURAPPID}&pages=1

Comment: And you can point to your page directly:
https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key={YOUR_APP_ID}&pages=1&page={YOUR_PAGE_ID} Much more cleaner on page admin point of view.

Comment: Funnily enough, that's the OLD URL, and apart from the fact it's a useful workaround for the current bug, i really don't recommend using it

Answer (score 0):

Fix is coming soon:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/304168516342380?browse=search_4fd087c2f30b06d49200886

Answer (score 0):

a detailed article presenting the problem and a workaround [Solution to adding Facebook App to Page](http://blog.aswinlutchanah.info/2012/06/06/facebook-app-add-page-tab-bug/)

Some more parameter to personnalize the implementation can be found too !

Answer (score 0):

When you have included the Javascript SDK you can call a nice dialog to select the target page for your app to add:

```
var obj = {
            method: 'pagetab'
        };

FB.ui(obj);
```

Comment: There's a currently-open bug with that dialog